# Ruby on Rails' gem "Devise" doesn't even have a controller file in app/controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, devise

After installing Devise, there are routes to

```
/users/sign_in
/users/sign_up
/users/sign_out
```

but there is no file `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`?  why does this require no controller file or is it just some where else?

Answer (score 3):

The controller file is located within the gem, and you don't need to write one yourself. Most everything can be done via configuration. See https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#readme for more specific details.

You can, however, generate the views so that you may override them yourself:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

That will place files in app/views/devise that you can modify for all of the forms, etc. that Devise provides.

Answer (score 2):

It's bundled with the gem. You can generate a controller 'User' separately with further actions:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```